# How to select QTableView index or row from inside of Model

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

The posted code creates a singe `Model/Proxy` `QTableView`. The multi-selection feature has been enabled for it.

[image]

There are four items total. Two of them include a character "A". Other two include character "B" in their "item" names.

`QPushButton` when pressed calls for the `clicked()` method.
When called this method first queries a `Proxy Model` connected to the `QTableView`:

```
proxyModel=self.tableview.model()
```

Then the method asks a `proxyModel` to return a total number of rows:

```
rows=proxyModel.rowCount()
```

Knowing how many rows in a `QTabelView`'s model it iterates each row. First it is querying a row index:

```
index=proxyModel.index(row, 0)
```

Knowing `index` it proceeds with asking for a value stored in `self.items` variable by calling `data()` method supplying it with a queried in a previous step a `QModelIndex` (a variable `index` here) and a `Role` flag.

```
item=proxyModel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject()
```

'toPyObject()' is used to convert the data received from `.data()` method to a "regular" Python variable.

Lastly it checks if the characters "*B*" in a received string. If so it selects QTableView row using:

```
self.tableview.selectRow(row)
```

Now what I want is to get the same selection functionality from inside of the scope of Proxy Model's `filterAcceptsRow()` if that is possible.

If it is not possible I would like to know if there is any other way of doing it... should be I using `QItemSelectionModel`? Then how?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_A_001','Item_A_002','Item_B_001','Item_B_002']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        return True

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        proxyModel=Proxy()
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        self.tableview=QTableView(self) 
        self.tableview.setModel(proxyModel)
        self.tableview.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableview.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        button=QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('Select Items with B')
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def clicked(self, arg):
        proxyModel=self.tableview.model()

        self.tableview.clearSelection()
        rows=proxyModel.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            index=proxyModel.index(row, 0)
            item=proxyModel.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject()
            if '_B_' in item:
                self.tableview.selectRow(row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the selection within the `filterAcceptsRow()` method of the proxy model, but doing so would require the following:

1. That your proxy model (or source model) contain a reference to the `QTableView` instance.
2. That your proxy model contain an attribute indicating whether it is active. This is because you want to only select the table rows when the button is clicked, but `filterAcceptsRow()` is called automatically by the proxy model. Therefore, you would want to avoid calling the view's `selectRow()` method until the button is clicked.

To achieve #1, you could define a simple setter method in your proxy model class:

```
def setView(self, view):
    self._view = view
```

You would also need to of course invoke that setter within your `MyWindow` class's constructor:

```
proxyModel.setView(self.tableview)
```

Achieving #2 is a simple matter of creating this attribute in the proxy model class's constructor

```
self.filterActive = False
```

Now that your classes are prepared, you can implement your desired behavior. In your `filterAcceptsRow()` re-implementation, you only want to select the rows if they contain `'_B_'` and is the filter is active (that is, the button was clicked):

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
    if self.filterActive and '_B_' in self.sourceModel().data(self.sourceModel().index(row, 0), Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject():
        self._view.selectRow(row)
    return True
```

Finally, you want to make sure that these conditions are met once the button is clicked, so in your clicked() method you need to set the `proxyModel`'s `filterActive` attribute to True and you need to call the `QSortFilterProxyModel` class's `invalidateFilter()` method to indicate that the existing filter is invalid and therefore `filterAcceptsRow()` should be called again:

```
def clicked(self, arg):
    proxyModel=self.tableview.model()
    self.tableview.clearSelection()
    proxyModel.filterActive = True
    proxyModel.invalidateFilter()
```

So the new code, in full, is:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_A_001','Item_A_002','Item_B_001','Item_B_002']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()
        self.filterActive = False

    def setView(self, view):
        self._view = view

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if self.filterActive and '_B_' in self.sourceModel().data(self.sourceModel().index(row, 0), Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject():
            self._view.selectRow(row)
        return True

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        proxyModel=Proxy()
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        self.tableview=QTableView(self) 
        self.tableview.setModel(proxyModel)
        self.tableview.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableview.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        proxyModel.setView(self.tableview)

        button=QPushButton(self)
        button.setText('Select Items with B')
        button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def clicked(self, arg):
        proxyModel=self.tableview.model()
        self.tableview.clearSelection()
        proxyModel.filterActive = True
        proxyModel.invalidateFilter()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Having said all of that, the purpose of `filterAcceptsRow()` is so that you can implement your own custom *filtering* in a subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel`. So, a more typical implementation (following your desired rule) would be:

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
    if not self.filterActive or '_B_' in self.sourceModel().data(self.sourceModel().index(row, 0), Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject():
        return True
    return False
```

And even then, because the filtering could be done with regex, reimplementation of `filterAcceptsRow()` isn't even necessary. You could just call `proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp("_B_", Qt.CaseInsensitive, QRegExp.FixedString))` and `proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)` to achieve the same thing, filter-wise.

Hope that helps!